# Trouble getting HTML Select data into POST.PHP

Tags: php, html-select

I have an input.php file with a form containing two types of lookup fields.  One is populated from a series of `<option>` tags ($grade_1) and the other field is populated from a column in a database ($role_1).  Both lookup fields display fine in the input.php form.  I'm having trouble getting the user's selection based on database input ($role_1)into the post.php.  I used ISSET as test code to see if I could get the count and data for $role_1.  I can echo the Count ($nroles), but the echo of the data element ($role_1) doesn't display.  The variable $grade_1 works fine.
Here's part of the input form:

```
<?php $link = new mysqli("localhost","USER","PASSWORD", "DATABASE");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {   printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    if (!$link->set_charset("utf8")) 
    {   printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $link->error);
        exit();
    }
    $role_sql = "SELECT role FROM lu_role";
    $role_result2 = mysqli_query($link, $role_sql) or die (mysqli_error($link));
    $options = "";
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($role_result2))
    {
        $options = $options."<option value=''>$row2[0]</option>";
    }
?>
<form action="post.php" method="post">
    <table class="table_600_reg">
      <tr>
        <td width="120">
         <select name="grade_1" style="background-color:#EFD381;">
            <option value="0">Choose Grade</option>
            <option value="1">First</option>
            <option value="2">Second</option>
            <option value="3">Third</option>
            <option value="4">Fourth</option>
            <option value="5">Fifth</option>
            <option value="6">Sixth</option>
            <option value="7">Seventh</option>
            <option value="8">Eighth</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td width="200" align="left">
            <select name="role_1" style="background-color:#EFD381;">
                <?php echo $options;?>
            </select>               
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

A snippet from the Post.PHP file is:

```
$link = new mysqli("localhost","USER","PASSWORD", "DATABASE");
  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
   printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
  exit();
}
//* change character set to utf8 */
//Print an error if utf8 can not be loaded
if (!$link->set_charset("utf8")) 
{
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $link->error);
    exit();
}
$role_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST[role_1]);
$grade_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST[grade_1]);
if(!isset($role_1)) 
  {
    echo("<p>You didn't select any role_1!</p>\n");
  } 
else
  {
    $nroles = count($role_1);
    echo("<p>You selected $nroles roles: ");
    for($i=0; $i < $nroles; $i++)
    {
      echo($role_1[$i] . " ");
    }
    echo("</p>");
    exit;
  }
```

Why can't I see the data from the $role_1 variable?
Thanks for looking at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$options = $options."<option value=''>$row2[0]</option>";
```

value is Empty String

Comment: Hi.  Sorry, I don't get what you mean.  Should I replace value='' with something else?

Comment: Update:  I replaced value='' with value='$row2[0]' and now I get only the first character of the value the user selected.  It seems to be passing only one character position.  Is there a way I could alter this to pass a variable of, say, 16 characters?

Comment: Another Update:  Replacing value='' with value=$row2[0]' did the trick.  I coded the ISSET incorrectly and it was throwing me off.  When I replaced the ISSET lines with a simple ECHO of $role1, it displayed the full string.

Comment: $options = $options."<option value=''>$row2[0]</option>";

Comment: Change to
$options = $options."<option value='{$row2[0]}'>{$row2[0]}</option>";